# Step detector using android accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

i am building an app that counts the steps using accelerometer for android devices.(android version< .4.4)

to do this i calculate the gravity (G) using x,y and z. if the value of G is larger than STEP_THRESHOLD then an step has been occured:

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            return;
        }

        final float x = event.values[0];
        final float y = event.values[1];
        final float z = event.values[2];
        final float g = Math.abs((x * x + y * y + z * z) / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH));

        if (g > StepUtil.GRAVITY_THRESHOLD) {
            /*
            * check step times and other checkings
            */
             .
             .
             .
            stepCounter++;
        }

    }
}
```

the problem is:
since accelerometer hardwares is varies in each device, there is not a certain value for STEP_THRESHOLD.
it seems that the STEP_THRESHOLD value should be dynamic for each device!
is there any criterion to change STEP_THRESHOLD value base on accelerometer accuracy?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since accelerometer hardwares is varies in each deviceو there is not a certain value for STEP_THRESHOLD

Having that said, what your app is apparently missing is simple **calibration**, which would allow your users to set the threshold level on their device. Tell them to do couple of steps, take sensor values, take mean/median/average (whatever will work for you better) and you got your STEP_THRESHOLD. You can even send this value back to your server so you can build kind of database and come with some more/less universtal starting value of STEP_AVERAGE.